# Media Sharing CMS Site

Tags: content-management-system, youtube, media, multimedia

We are trying to build a media sharing site. I want to use existing commercial or open source frameworks if they are available.

I saw some sites like:

1. http://www.phpmotion.com/
2. http://www.jamroom.net
3. http://www.clip-share.com/
4. http://www.videoscript.us
5. http://www.vidiscript.com/
6. http://www.alstrasoft.com/videoshare.htm

Are there any good open source (or) commercial packages that I am missing out? I want the media site to stream normal as well as HD content and integrate with a payment gateway when the user wants to view HD.

Comment: has anyone found a good one? preferably open source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the primary developer of Jamroom (http://www.jamroom.net) - while Jamroom is a commercially licensed system, it is "open source" in the fact that we do not encrypt the PHP code in any way, and our license allows for full modifications to suit your needs.

Let me know if you have any questions and I can follow up.  Thanks!

- Brian

Answer (score 0):

I will research your listed sites. i will come back with good one.

There is available one more [video sharing script: http://www.rayzz.net/index.php][1]